# What's a lightweight alternative to Word / Writer?

Tags: documents, writing

I'm looking for a desktop, cross-OS, Word/Writer-like program (this is, that lets the user format the content, as opposed to source code editors) without all the feature bloat + performance overhead I'd get with an office suite.

Ideally, most of its features would be focused on:

- the text editing itself - clever replaces, indentation control, etc, and
- separating the content from its presentation, à la HTML/CSS.

Which programs match these features?

Comment: "Word/Writer-like program" = *text processor*, as opposed to *text editor* :)

Answer (score 3):

For the former, i tend to favour [abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) it is light, and does wordprocessing pretty well, with a sane UI. Can't say i know of any word processor that does the latter, and seperates content and presentation

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.productivity501.com/free-word-processors/5578/) is a list of 11 free text processors. [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) is listed first and is probably what you're looking for.